# How to access array data from api in ionic 3

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I want to access array data and display this data in ion-select.

**html**

```
<ion-item>
   <ion-label>Select Time</ion-label>
      <ion-select  interface ="popover">
        <div *ngFor="let item of items">
           <ion-option > {{item}}</ion-option>
        </div>
      </ion-select>
```

**ts file**

```
ionViewDidLoad(){

   let url = 'http://mysiteurl/wp-json/wp/v2/authores/4';

    this.http.get(url, this.config.options).map(res => res.json())
          .subscribe((response: any) => {
              this.items = response;
              response.forEach(item => 
              console.log(this.item));
       }, (err) => {
           let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
           title: 'Error',
          subTitle: 'Please check your credentials',
          buttons: ['OK']
          });
      alert.present();
    });
   }
 }
```

and this is my api response

```
[
"09:00 AM -12:00 PM",
"12:00 PM - 03:00 PM",
"05:00 PM - 07:00 PM"
]
```

[image]

How to access these values in my ion-select option.I am not able to do that.

Comment: `console.log(this.item)` is invalid. Do you want to just print `item` or `this.items`?

Comment: i just want these values in ion-select..

Comment: What does `console.log(response)` print just inside `subscribe`?

Comment: console.log(response) print whole response .i attached the image of my response in above question...the image showing the console.log(response).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@saif khan.. remove spaces in your html

```
 <ion-item>
       <ion-label>Select Time</ion-label>
          <ion-select [(ngModel)]="item" interface ="popover">
            <div *ngFor="let item of items">
               <ion-option>{{item}}</ion-option>
            </div>
          </ion-select>
```

and then in the  component

```
 this.http.get(url, this.config.options)
    .map(res => res.json()).subscribe((response: any) => {
          this.items = response;   //this will store your response in items
          response.forEach(item => {
          //if you want print each item in the console
          console.log(item);
           });
        });
```

Comment: [ngMode)]="item" is missing in <ion-select  interface ="popover">